# Snakemake use the wrong environment

Tags: python, conda, snakemake

I'm calling Snakemake workflow from a shell script.
But first I need to activate an environment that contains snakemake and other libraries installed.

```
source ${CONDA_HOME}/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate myenv
# then call the workflow.
```

Rules in the snakemake workflow use `conda:` to create their own environment.
one of the rules uses python to run some script:

```
rule readsStat:
    """
    Input is the reads output is info about reads
    """
    input: expand(data_dir + "/{sample}", sample=sample_list)
    output:data_dir + "/statitics/raw_reads/reads_stat.txt",
    message: "Calculating read coverage statitics for: {input}",
    params:
        read_stat_script = rawcoverage_script,
    threads: config['read_raw_coverage_threads']
    benchmark: data_dir + "/benchmark/raw_reads/stat.benchmark.txt"
    conda: STAT_ENV
    shell:
        """
        python {params.read_stat_script} -i {input} -o {output} -t {threads}
        """
```

The issue is after the rule activates the proper environment instead of using it (e.x., `.snakemake/conda/532a617ec7374b7bff46f066e73/bin/python`), they still use `myenv` python `envs/myenv/bin/python` that I activated earlier in the calling script.

Any idea how can I fix that?

Thanks

**Update:**
versions
`conda 4.10.1`
`Snakemake 6.2.1`

Comment: I don't know if it's related but `source ...` suggests that either you are using an old version of conda or conda is not properly installed since you shouldn't need to do that. Can you give more detail about conda and snakemake versions, how you execute them and ideally a minimal example?

Comment: Just to be sure, are you running with `--use-conda`?  What you've described looks ok (in terms of snakemake).

Comment: @dariober I updated the question, adding both conda, snakemake versions, and the rule example. I tried to activate the environment and run the snakemake directly  (no wrap script), still face the same issue.

Comment: @TroyComi yes I use `--use-conda`

Comment: @dariober Thank you, removing the source command line made it work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in line:
`source ${CONDA_HOME}/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`
removing this line made Snakemake works as expected.
Thanks